# Sharepoint 2010 List Creation Limit

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Does anyone knows if sharepoint 2010 have some kind of limitation related to list creation? I need to create a web application with 120.000 lists for a specific reason. It is that possible? There will be some performance issues?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think theres a limitation for how many lists you can create, however, there is an overall limitation of list items / size. Check out [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) article.

If you really need to create that many lists, you might want to redo your solution design.

Comment: You're right. The client ask us this question as an alternative to solve their problem. But thanks anyway.